# Can't Figure Out Specific RegEx

Tags: regex

I've trying to get a regular expression to work with no luck. I've been able to to limit the expression to an alphanumeric number with 10 digits:

`(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}+$)`

however i am also trying to get it allow the $ character with only 1 match in any position.

it should come up as true for something like, `pQp3b8ar$8` or `k7DdRoB$5W`.

Comment: I am not sure if it is doable with regex without exhausting all 10 positions of $ signs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three general notes:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9$]{10}$
```

- the parentheses are not necessary
- `{10}+` does not make much sense, drop the plus (there's no need for a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) on a fixed count)
- if you want to allow a dollar sign, just add it to the character class

---

To allow a dollar sign only once, you can use an extended version of the above:

```
^(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9$]{10}$
```

The `(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)` is a look-ahead that reads

```
(?=        # start look-ahead
  [^$]*    #   any number of non-dollar signs
  \$       #   a dollar sign
  [^$]*    #   any number of non-dollar signs
  $        #   the end of the string
)          # end of look-ahead
```

It allows any characters on the string but the dollar only once.

---

Another variant would be to use two look-aheads, like this:

```
^(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9$]{10}$).*
```

Here you can use the `.*` to match the remainder of the string since the two conditions are checked by the look-aheads. This approach is useful for [password complexity checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation), for example.

Comment: Thats close, but how would you only accept 1 $ allowed? If I put in qFYg64E$h$ i want it to come up false as compared to true for qFYg64Ehh$.

Comment: Nice, also thanks for the explanation as well, makes it easier to know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to match a string that contains two strings of any number of alphanumeric characters with a `$` in the middle.

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+$)
```

You can always check the length of ten after the regex.