# javascript regex to require at least one special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've seen plenty of regex examples that will not allow any special characters.  I need one that requires at least one special character.

I'm looking at a C# regex

```
var regexItem = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$");
```

Can this be converted to use with javascript?  Do I need to escape any of the characters?

Based an example I have built this so far:

```
var regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$";

//Must have one special character
if (regex.exec(resetPassword)) {
    isValid = false;
    $('#vsResetPassword').append('Password must contain at least 1 special character.');
}
```

Can someone please identify my error, or guide me down a more efficient path? The error I'm currently getting is that regex has no 'exec' method

Comment: Have you looked at any documentation on how Javascript uses regexes?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/936/ Just sayin'

Comment: @WaleedKhan How do you think I created my example?

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation

Comment: @AlexWayne, I don't set requirements, I'm just a coding monkey ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$"` is a string, and you need a regex:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/;                 // one way
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$");     // another way
```

[[more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)]

Other than that, your code looks fine.

Comment: You fixed his error but this is disallowing anything except a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or spaces. It's not requiring a special character.

Comment: @DominicTobias: This regex will *match* a string that contains no special characters, but it, in and of itself, doesn't "require" or "disallow" anything. Rather, the OP's code will reject any password that matches this regex; so it requires the password to contain at least one special character, by disallowing any password that doesn't.

Comment: Ah yeah, perhaps that's a better approach than looking for a specific list of characters

Comment: @DominicTobias: I think either approach is equally fine. (You don't need a *specific* list of special characters; the complement of this regex is just `/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/`.) Regexes are an incredibly powerful tool, but so is `!`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, regexs are formatted like this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/
```

Note that there are no quotation marks and instead you use forward slashes at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can create a regular expression object two ways.

1)  You can use the constructor method with the `RegExp` object (note the different spelling than what you were using):

```
var regexItem = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$");
```

2)  You can use the literal syntax built into the language:

```
var regexItem = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/;
```

The advantage of the second is that you only have to escape a forward slash, you don't have to worry about quotes.  The advantage of the first is that you can programmatically construct a string from various parts and then pass it to the RegExp constructor.

---

Further, the optional flags for the regular expression are passed like this in the two forms:

```
var regexItem = new RegExp("^[A-Z0-9 ]*$", "i");
var regexItem = /^[A-Z0-9 ]*$/i;
```

In javascript, it seems to be a more common convention to the user `/regex/` method that is built into the parser unless you are dynamically constructing a string or the flags.