# JAVA Regex for password validation issue

Tags: java, regex

i have a regexp for password validation ( [Regexp Java for password validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation) 
with extra special characters)

```
String pattern ="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=!\\*_?|~(){}/<>:\"\',\\[\\]`;\\\\\\\\-])(?=\\S+$).{8,}$";
```

The issue with this is, 
if i say

```
 "Xyz.123".matches(pattern);
```

This returns `false`

However, if i say

```
  "Xyz.123$".matches(pattern);
```

This returns `true`

'.' is not a valid special characters in my case. But if my password has a valid special character along with '.' it returns `true`

Comment: Out of curiosity, remove the `$` from the end of the regex.

Comment: @destroy `$` doesn't need escaping inside character groups, and `^` will only be a special character if immediately preceeded by `[`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `\\S+`, which means "any non-space character."  `.` satisfies that.  You also need the `$` to satisfy the third pseudo-condition (lookahead).  `.` is not in that, but `$` is.

EDIT: If you do not want any periods at all, change the last pseudo-condition to `(?=[^\\s.]+$)`

Comment: I am very new to REGEX. Can you please provide me the correction in the regex or actual regex. Thanks

Comment: @Shoaib I don't understand what the problem is.  You don't want to allow periods?

Comment: 1. Yes, I don't want to allow periods.

Comment: @Shoaib change `(?=\\S+$)` at the end to `(?=[^\s.]+$)`

Comment: 1. Yes, I don't want to allow periods. 2. If a user enters period in his password, the regex does not match his password and returns "FALSE" , this helps me notifying the user to re-enter password. 3. But, the issue is, if a user enters a password with a period, along with some other special characters(that are permitted in my regex ), say the user enters password "Password@123.321" Then the regex does match this new password and returns TRUE. which is not an expected behaviour since i do not have a period in my REGEX. Thanks

Comment: @Shoaib why did you ignore my last comment?  Change `(?=\\S+$)` to `(?=[^\\s.]+$)`

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) It works. I missed your comments, was editing my reply and the comments did not show up.

Comment: Hi, This solution is working for period. I am facing same issue with other special characters which are not allowed in my regex(e.g. ¡¢£¥¦§¨ª«¬). Can you please provide a universal solution for the not allowing special characters apart from the one listed in the Regex. Thanks

Comment: @Shoaib you would have to create a whitelist of allowed characters instead of a blacklist (i.e. `(?=[0-9A-Za-z@#$%^&+=!\\*_?|~(){}/<>:\"\',\\[\\]\`;\\\\\\\\-]+$)` at the end)