# RegEx - Java - Matching Strings (012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|890)

Tags: java, regex, string, passwords, match

I am working on password enhancement and client wants a password that does not have consecutive letters ie: 123, 234.

I have figured out that you can declare strings that you want to match in regex like `(012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|890)` and made it as the regex sequence.

This sequence is separated from the other sequences for easy reading.

The problem is, I cannot match the password with the pattern even if I included 123 or 234 in the password character.

I've read that regex cannot detect 123 as consecutive numbers, but as a string, can it do so?

Comment: Regexes are always working on strings. They have no idea about the meaning of the characters, e.g. they don't know that 2 is one more than 1

Comment: Please post your code with the string that is not matched and where you apply the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a limited sequence of characters following one another you can use a `Pattern`, `.find()` on a matcher on your input and just invert the test:

```
// Only the alternation is needed, no need for the capture
private static final Pattern PATTERN
    = Pattern.compile("012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|890");

// ...

if (PATTERN.matcher(input).find())
    // fail: illegal sequence found
```

But if you want to detect that code points follow one another you have to use character functions:

```
final CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.wrap(input);

int maxSuccessive = 0;
int successive = 0;
char prev = buf.get();
char next;

while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
    next = buf.get();
    if (next - prev == 1)
        successive++;
    else {
        maxSuccessive = Math.max(maxSuccessive, successive);
        successive = 0;
    }
    prev = next;
}

// test maxSuccessive
```

Note however that this will test successive characters according to "canonical ordering", not collation. In some locales, for instance, what is immediately after `a` is `A`, not `b`.

---

More generally, if you want to test for password requirements and constraint evolves, you are better off splitting things a bit. For instance, consider this:

```
public interface PasswordChecker
{
    boolean isValid(final String passwd);
}
```

Implement this interface for each of your checks (for instance, length, presence/absence of certain characters, etc), and when you do check for a password, have a `List` of checkers; the password is invalid if one checker returns false:

```
private final List<PasswordChecker> checkers = ...;

// then

for (final PasswordChecker checker: checkers)
    if (!checker.isValid(passwd))
        return false;
return true;
```

If you use Guava, you can forget about `PasswordChecker` and use `Predicate<String>`.

Comment: Thank you very much! `if (PATTERN.matcher(input).find())` worked for me.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that just now. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're only dealing with *these*  strings of digits that you want to exclude, you can achieve this using a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!.*(012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|890))<regex>
```

where `<regex>` is the actual regex you're using to match the password, and `(?!...)` is the lookahead that asserts it's impossible to match that string in your regex.

If you're asking about *any* increasing sequence of characters, then regex is not the right tool for this. You would have to do that programmatically.

Comment: Why not just use `.find()` and invert the test?

Comment: @fge: Sure, if you want to do a series of tests one after another instead of a single large (possibly unwieldy) regex, that would be a valid strategy as well.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I am using 6 regex patterns now to check for the other requirements.

Comment: That will quickly become unsustainable... Find another strategy to test for passwords

Comment: @user2571732: Well, you can put multiple checks into a regex, and if you use `Pattern.COMMENTS` mode, you can even write them understandably (and possibly easier to read than a complicated programmatic solution. YMMV). See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation