# java regular expression digits, letters, uppercase, lowercase

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression in Java with the following requirements:

- can only contain letters and digits
- must at least contain one digit
- must contain at least one upperCase letter AND one lowerCase letter

I have tried several expressions that don't work - this is the best so far:

```
(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation

Comment: what is your question? Your regex is good

Comment: The problem is with this requirement: can only contain letters and digits. The current regex accepts other characters - and it must not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor your regex, and don't use `.` which allows anything:

```
^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

`^$` matches beginning and end of string, `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` makes sure the characters are only those in the character class.