# Regex for password validation. I know there are lots of infomation but I can't wrap my head around it

Tags: java, regex

My requirements are this:

- at least 8 characters,
- must contain at least 1 lowercase
- must contain at least 1 uppercase
- must contain at least one numeral
- must contain at least one of the following set: `!@#$%^&*`
- must not contain "and" or "end"

That last part is the part that is tripping me up I googled a bunch and came up with:

```
^(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\S{8,}$
```

But I believe that it will allow ALL special characters because of `\S` if I understand that post. I can't have that. I also need to check to see if the string contains `and` or `end`.

Currently I have this. and it works, but it's not elegant.

```
package testing;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordTest {

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Start");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done = false;       
    while(!done){
        boolean size = false;
        boolean upper = false;
        boolean lower = false;
        boolean special = false;
        boolean andEnd = false;
        boolean numeric = false;
        String password = sc.nextLine();
        if(password.length()>=8){
            size=true;
        }
        for(int x = 0;x < password.length();x++){
            if(password.charAt(x)>= 65 && password.charAt(x)<=90){
                upper = true;
            }
            if(password.charAt(x)>= 97 && password.charAt(x)<=122){
                lower = true;
            }
            if(password.charAt(x)>= 48 && password.charAt(x)<=67){
                numeric = true;
            }
            if(password.charAt(x)>= 33 && password.charAt(x)<=42){
                special = true;
            }
        }
        if(!password.contains("and") && !password.contains("end")){
            andEnd = true;
        }
        if(!size){
            System.out.println("Password too short");
        }
        if(!upper){
            System.out.println("Password does not contain an uppercase character");
        }
        if(!lower){
            System.out.println("Password does not contain an lowercase character");
        }
        if(!numeric){
            System.out.println("Password does not contain a number");
        }
        if(!special){
            System.out.println("Password does not contain a Special character");
        }
        if(!andEnd){
            System.out.println("Password does contain 'and' or 'end'");
        }
        done = size && upper && lower && numeric && special&& andEnd;
        if(done){
            System.out.println("Valid "+password);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid "+password);
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
}
```

Comment: There are about a zillion similar questions.  Did you try the search facility before posting?

Comment: [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation).

Comment: Can't have "and" and "end"?  What kind of crazy requirement is that?

Comment: See also, Randall Munroe's thoughts on password complexity:  http://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you described the password, you can use this:

```
if (subjectString.matches("(?=.*[a-z])(?=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])(?!.*[ae]nd)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])\\S{8,}")) {
    // It matched!
  } 
else {  // nah, it didn't match...  
     }
```

- For the allowable character set, I would advise coming up for something more specific than `\S`. For instance, if you are happy to only have ASCII characters, instead `S{8,}` at the end, you could use `[!-~]{8,}` which allows any printable ASCII chars
- Each of the `(?=...)` is a lookahead that assert that something can be matched.
- The `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead that assert that something cannot be matched.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem for a single regular expression, instead you should validate each condition separately, only using a regex as appropriate.

```
Check that it contains a lowercase letter /[a-z]/
Check that it contains an upper case letter /[A-Z]/
Check the length password.length()
```

And so forth...

You want to make your code clear and easy to understand -- checking each condition separately does that.  Your approach with named booleans is a good start, it's the implementation that is incorrect.

**Edit**: I had originally missed the requirement to reject some special characters.  I added that in.  Making the test explicit will make changing and validating these conditions easier.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("Start");
    String password = getPassword()
    System.out.println("Valid "+password);

}

public static String getPassword(){
    boolean done = false;       
    String passwordCandidate;
    while(!done){
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       passwordCandidate = sc.nextLine();
       List<String> validationErrors = validate(passwordCandidate);

       done = validationErrors.size() == 0;
       if(!done){
            System.out.println("Invalid "+passwordCandidate);
            for(String errMsg : validationErrors) {
                 System.out.println(errMsg);
             }
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    return passwordCandidate;
}

public static List<String> validate(String passwordCandidate){
    List<String> errMsgs = new ArrayList<String>();

    boolean size = passwordCandidate.length()>=8;
    boolean upper = passwordCandidate.matches(".*[A-Z].*");
    boolean lower = passwordCandidate.matches(".*[a-z].*");
    boolean requiredSpecial = passwordCandidate.matches(".*[!@#$%^&*].*");
    boolean andEnd = !passwordCandidate.matches(".*[ae]nd.*");
    boolean numeric = passwordCandidate.matches(".*[0-9].*");
    boolean forbiddenSpecial = !passwordCandidate.matches(".*[^a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*].*");

    if(!size){
        errMsgs.add("Password too short");
    }
    if(!upper){
        errMsgs.add"Password does not contain an uppercase character");
    }
    if(!lower){
        errMsgs.add("Password does not contain an lowercase character");
    }
    if(!numeric){
        errMsgs.add("Password does not contain a number");
    }
    if(!requiredSpecial){
        errMsgs.add("Password does not contain a Special character");
    }
    if(!forbiddenSpecial){
        errMsgs.add("Password contains a forbidden character");
    }
    if(!andEnd){
        errMsgs.add("Password contains 'and' or 'end'");
    }
    return errMsgs

}
```

Comment: This can easily be done with one regular expression: see my comment.  If you actually want to tell the user what's wrong, then I agree, this shouldn't be done with one regex.

Comment: @SteveP.: I didn't say it couldn't be solved with a single regex, but it's not a problem *best* solved with a single regular expression.

Comment: The `matches()` method requires the regex to describe the whole string, so you need to "pad" all those regexes like so: `".*[A-Z].*"`, `".*[a-z].*"`, etc.  Also, you didn't address the requirement that characters other than `[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*]` are not allowed.