# How to check a string has a uppercase.lowercase or number?

Tags: java

Here i used this code for generating one password which should contain a uppercase,a lowercase and a number and a special char. this is my code for checking.

```
String randomPassword = genRanPass();
        boolean hasUppercase = !randomPassword.equals(randomPassword.toLowerCase());
        boolean hasLowercase = !randomPassword.equals(randomPassword.toUpperCase());
        boolean hasNumber  = randomPassword.matches(".*\\d.*");
        if(!(randomPassword.contains("!") || randomPassword.contains("@") || randomPassword.contains("#") || randomPassword.contains("$") || randomPassword.contains("_") || randomPassword.contains("-"))){
             while(!hasUppercase && hasLowercase && hasNumber) 
             {
             randomPassword = genRanPass();
             }

          }else{

             while(!hasUppercase && hasLowercase && hasNumber) 
                 {
                 randomPassword = genRanPass();
                 }

                return randomPassword;

        }

genRanPass(); generating a password having random number,a spcial char,a letter Uppercase and lower case

but i got hnga$VVj from my method  and when i am checking 

while(!hasUppercase && hasLowercase && hasNumber) 
                 {
                 randomPassword = genRanPass();
                 }

                return randomPassword;
   while(!hasUppercase && hasLowercase && hasNumber) its became true,true and false,its not going inside this method plase help me.
                 {
```

Comment: That's Cool - have a nice day.

Comment: You should seriously consider using REGEX.

Comment: As TheLostMind mentioned consider the REGEX. Follow the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation to kick start.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you use a straight forward [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and the utility methods from [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html). Something like,

```
public static boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    if (password == null) return false;
    boolean hasUpper = false;
    boolean hasLower = false;
    boolean hasNumber = false;
    boolean hasSpecial = false;
    for (char ch : password.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            hasUpper = true;
        } else if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
            hasLower = true;
        } else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            hasNumber = true;
        } else {
            hasSpecial = true;
        }
    }
    return hasUpper && hasLower && hasNumber && hasSpecial;
}
```