# Code for creating a for loop to validate password. Is this correct? (without regexp)

Tags: java, validation, passwords

The task was to create a Java program to check if a password is valid.
The criteria involved:
- Has 6 characters
- Starts with a letter

I also need to test the password to see if valid and display a message saying. "valid password" or "invalid password

```
  for(int i = 0; i < password.length();i++)
{
    char ch = password.charAt(i); //checks if charachter is letter or digit
    if (Character.isLetter(ch))
    {
        num++;
    }
    else
    {
        let++;

    }

}   
txaDisplay.append("Number of Letters:"+let);
txaDisplay.append("\n Number of Digits:"+num);


char valid = password.charAt(0);
if (Character.isLetter(valid))
    {
        num++;
    }
    else
    {
        let++;

    }
txaDisplay.append("Password is valid");
txaDisplay.append("Password is invalid");
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate password regular expression would be a better option please check with 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation)

Comment: I am not allowed to use reg exp.