# creating a password regex (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a password regex that:

- is at least 8 characters in length
- must start with a capital letter, followed by a number
- have one of these special characters (#@*)
- contains exactly 3 numbers at the end of the password

This is what I have tried so far:

```
/^([A-Z][\d])([#@*]{1})([A-Za-z0-9]+)([\d]{3})$/
```

The problem with this so far is that it is only allowing a special character to come after the number.

For example: It allows **A4#Fgf344** but not **A4Fg#f344**.

Comment: This has been asked about a hundred times on SO--did you look? Also, please tell your boss/client that these kinds of rules are **really, really** stupid and obnoxious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regexp Java for password validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because these kinds of password restrictions are dangerous.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to use regex properly, it is not for a client or some kind of company, just for my own personal gain

Comment: Understanding you are simply just trying to learn more on regex (which can be tricky, good luck!), I still have to recommend for you to never store password information within a JavaScript file - we can retrieve it easily. If you have a database (MySql for example), start by looking into md5 hashing via PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=[^#@*]*[#@*][^#@*]*$)([A-Z][\d])([A-Za-z0-9#@*]+)([\d]{3})$
```

Try this.This should do it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/50

Comment: thank you @vks. This is helpful. I still don't have a clear understanding of look around, but in all this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[A-Z]\d(?=.*?[#@*]).{3,}\d{3}$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ1lD0/1)