# HTML5 browser password validation (valid pattern attribute!): minimum 6 chars and at least 1 number and 1 Capital letter

Tags: regex, html

I'm stuck with HTML5 embedded form validation (non javascript).
I need to meet all this parameters:

1. minimum 6 chars
2. at least 1 number
3. at least 1 Capital letter

Could you help me to make sure it works as pattern attribute? For example:

`<input type="password" pattern="myPattern" />`
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regexp Java for password validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation)

Comment: I dived in many of regular expressions, I need just to get it to work as 'pattern' attribute inside the input tag.

Comment: There are patterns in the answers for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you guys, I have found a working example and modified it:

```
<input type="password" pattern="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=\S+$).{6,}$" />
```

edit: corrected typo

Comment: A shorter one - `pattern="(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\S{6,}"`