# How to check for legal character in a username / password

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

The following code should test 2 strings (username and password) for length and allowed characters (should be 0-9. a-z, A-Z). the legalCharacters ArrayList is filled with characters a-z and 0-9.

testing for appropriate length works, but not for legal characters
this test returns an illegal characters error in the username:
user: aba
pass: aba

```
public DataResponseType checkForDataErrors(String username, String password) {
    responseType = null;
    boolean isIllegalUsername = false;
    boolean isIllegalPassword = false;
    if (username.length() < 3 || username.length() > 15) {
        responseType = DataResponseType.INVALID_USERNAME_LENGTH;
    } else if (password.length() < 3 || password.length() > 15) {
        responseType = DataResponseType.INVALID_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
    } else {
        for (int x = 0; x < username.length(); x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < legalCharacters.size(); z++) {
                Character test = username.toLowerCase().charAt(x);
                if (!test.equals(legalCharacters.get(z))) {
                    if (z == legalCharacters.size() - 1) {
                        isIllegalUsername = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isIllegalUsername) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < password.length(); x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < legalCharacters.size(); z++) {
                Character test = password.toLowerCase().charAt(x);
                if (!test.equals(legalCharacters.get(z))) {
                    if (z == legalCharacters.size() - 1) {
                        isIllegalPassword = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isIllegalPassword) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isIllegalUsername) {
            responseType = DataResponseType.INVALID_USERNAME_CHARACTERS;
        } else if (isIllegalPassword) {
            responseType = DataResponseType.INVALID_PASSWORD_CHARACTERS;
        } else {
            responseType = DataResponseType.VALID;
        }
    }
    return responseType;
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? or do it in a easier way (I don't understand how predicates work and haven't been able to find a good explanation)?
If other code is needed, please ask.

Comment: Did you read about regular expressions?

Comment: Use regex .It makes the job easy below link can help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8148112/2863159

Comment: Example regex:  `if (!username.matches("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$")) responseType = DataResponseType.INVALID_USERNAME_CHARACTERS;`

Answer (score 0):

Checking for legal characters is an ideal use case for regular expressions, see for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/, in particular character classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm always sets the `isIllegalUsername` flag to `false` if the current character is not *the last character in the `legalCharacters` collection*. This happens because you don't stop the inner loop once you've found a legal character matching the current character, e.g.:

```
boolean isLegalUsername = false;
...
if (test.equals(legalCharacters.get(z))) {
  isLegalUsername = true;
  break;
}
```

Apart from that, you can easily skip the second for-loop by using [`List.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) and setting the flag according to the result.

```
if(!legalCharacters.contains(test)) {
  isIllegalUsername = true;
}
```

Or, better yet, use regular expression as stated in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to step back here. You are already doing down a dangerous path.

You keep addition one little validation here; and another one there. Your code is already in pretty *bad* shape. I would suggest a much more OOP solution, something like this.

First, create an interface like:

```
public interface Validator() {
   public void check(String content) throws ValidiationException;
}
```

And then you implement **each** validation in its **own** class that implements this interface.

Then you do something like:

```
public class DataChecker {
  private final static List<Validator> validators = Arrays.asList(new LengthValidator, new BlaValidator, new ... );
```

and actual validation turns into:

```
try {
  for (Validator v : validators) {       
    v.check(someString);
  }
  // passed all checks
} catch (ValidationException v) {
  // v contains details such as: a nice error message to give to the user!
```

And for the *actual* implementation of these little classes; refer to the other answers you got. But as said: you should not only focus on the *functionality* you need to implement, but on the readability and maintainability of the code you are writing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the brute force method you are trying:

```
class Main {
    public static boolean isValid(String value) {
        String legalCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxzy0123456789";
        boolean valid = true;
        if (value.length() < 3 || value.length() > 15) {
            valid = false;
        }
        else {
            // For each character in the value
            for (int x = 0; x < value.length() ; x++) {
                boolean found = false;
                // Look for the character in legalCharacters
                for (int z = 0; z < legalCharacters.length(); z++) {
                    char c = value.charAt(x);
                    c = java.lang.Character.toLowerCase(c);
                    // If we found the character
                    if (c == legalCharacters.charAt(z)) {
                        // Remember we found it
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                // If we did not find it
                if (!found) {
                    // This is an invalid value
                    valid = false;
                    // Break out of the outer for loop
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "aba";
        String password = "aba";
        System.out.format("is %s valid: %b%n", username, isValid(username));
        System.out.format("is %s valid: %b%n", password, isValid(password));
        username = "###";
        password = "@@@";
        System.out.format("is %s valid: %b%n", username, isValid(username));
        System.out.format("is %s valid: %b%n", password, isValid(password));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
is aba valid: true
is aba valid: true
is ### valid: false
is @@@ valid: false
```

Try it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Ixad)