# Extract Complex Passwords From Text

Tags: regex, passwords

Passwords should contain: uppercase and lowercase letters and (Digit OR Symbol)

So, how can I extract from lines having above rules from a password list?

**Example:**

```
123q
123
qwe
!@#123
123@
Qwe1
Admin
admin
Admin@
Admin#1
```

**What I need:**

```
Qwe1
Admin@
Admin#1
```

Comment: how this list look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regexp Java for password validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation)

Comment: Which language is it for?

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub: PCRE regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead for each criteria for your password.

Here is a suggestion:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=.*[\d!@#$&*])(?=.*[a-z].*).*$
```

- `(?=.*[A-Z].*)` at least 1 uppercase
- `(?=.*[\d!@#$&*])` at least one character of the list (a special character or a number)
- `(?=.*[a-z].*)` at least 1 lowercase

#### [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/P7Ccrg/2)

Comment: Could you help me and explain a bit how the regex is using the positive lookaheads?  I'm trying to understand it based upon what I've read here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html but in the q(?=u) example I see it's the left 'character' and then followed by the lookahead, but I see no character to the left of your first lookahead.  Your code clearly works but I'm having trouble seeing how.  Thank you.

Comment: @sniperd For example, in `(?=.*[A-Z].*)`: `.*` whatever characters before, then `[A-Z]` an uppercase, and then again `.*` whatever characters after. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973609/4927984): `(?=REGEX_1)REGEX_2` matchs only if REGEX_1 matches; after matching REGEX_1, the match is discarded and searching for REGEX_2 starts at the same position.

Comment: would doing:  ^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d!@#$&*])(?=.*[a-z]).*$  also be OK in this specific case then?  Only having the first .*  in each 'set'  I'm really trying to wrap my head around this :)

Comment: @sniperd Nah, I don't think I will work. You need to say "I want an uppercase letter anywhere in the password". Without the ending `.*`, you do not say it may be anything after your uppercase. Get it? ;P

Comment: does the .* after all the look aheads take care of that though?  Thank you for your responses.  Every time I think have all the regex stuff figured out I find some puzzler!