# How to use matches method with password validation in Java

Tags: java, matcher

I am supposed to create a method in a different class that takes a string input and: "validate that a String represents 8 symbols, including letters (upper and lower case), numbers, and special symbols like #$&_."

This is my code so far.

```
public static boolean validSSN(String SSN)
{
    int length = SSN.length();
    boolean flag = false;
    if(length == 11)
    {
        if(SSN.matches("^\\d{3}[-]{1}\\d{2}[-]{1}\\d{4}")) flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question and/or problem?

Comment: At first glance 'validate String represents 8 symbols' and you have length == 11 ??? Then just play with regexp, you are here to learn you seem on the right track

Comment: Note 1: `flag = false; if (condition) flag = true;` is better represented by just `flag = condition;` (where condition is any expression resulting in a boolean)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger then " return condition;" would be even better

Comment: Note 2: `length == 11` if you want 8 characters (assuming that is meant by symbols) doesn't make sense

Comment: @Stultuske one step a time... [:-) and similar valid for variable `length`

Comment: Note 3: your regex does not resemble the specification in any way, is more like you got a code for checking something else (SSN `"ddd-dd-dddd"`), and `"[-]{1}"` is confusing (any character from the char set composed of just a minus, exactly one time? - the same as just `"-"` )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802238/7339164
Try to use expression from there.

Answer (score -1):

I may have found my solution to be:

```
if(pass.matches("^[A-Z|a-z|0-9|#|$|&|_]{8}")) flag =true;
```

instead of

```
if(SSN.matches("^\\d{3}[-]{1}\\d{2}[-]{1}\\d{4}")) flag = true;
```

Comment: You have no pass variable in your code, how do you think calling 'matches' on a non-existent variable will solve your problem?

Comment: Also,the OP ask a question without detail information and then answer it himself,I think both the answer and the question need to be deleted

Comment: And also the `|` symbol is not used in these `[]` brackets as **or** meaning.

Comment: Try this instead `^[\w\d\&\$\#]{8}$`.

Comment: If I understood the assignment right, it requires that letters AND digits AND spec chars should be present in the password, all of them, not just any of them.

Comment: better include the method as whole in this case... because of `SSN`/`pass` and with `length == 11` the above regex will never match (needs 8 characters).

Comment: by include I mean in the post, and BTW, there should be no `|` inside `[]` unless you want to match the specific character `'|'`. Inside of `[]` there is an *implicit* OR. Example `"[a-z0-9#]"` will match a lowercase character OR a digit OR a `#`