# regex password with min 8 characters, upper and lower Case, and no special character at Beginning and end

Tags: java, regex, passwords

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?=.+[a-z])(?=.+[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.+[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?])(\\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]){8,}?$
```

that is my regex for passwords. its wonky and not working all the time, for example : if i try ABcAcs!12 it doesnt work.

this is a task for my homeproject.
The password should:

- have minimum 8 characters,
- minimum 1 Upper and lower case alphabet,
- atleast 1 special character
- the special character is not allowed to be at the start or end of the
  String.

i have the feeling i need to completely overhaul it, but i hope you can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regexp Java for password validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation)

Comment: Unless this is an exercise in regex creation, I would just use POJ. I also think it would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

- The issue is that the pattern starts with matching 1 character in this character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

  At the end of the pattern, this part `(\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]){8,}` has to match at least 8 times one of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, and in the string `ABcAcs!12` there are 7 of them that match, being `ABcAcs` and `12`
- Also note that 2 of the lookaheads start with `.+` instead of `.*` meaning they don't take the first following character into account.

  This `9A9a$adfa` should be also valid, but due to the `.+` it misses the `A`
- As you want a miminum of 8, and you already have matched the first character, the quantifier at the end should be `{7,}`

The final pattern, using negated character classes to prevent backtracking could be

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*[0-9])(?=[^-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?])[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DNFdFo/1)

Answer (score 0):

Two slightly different approaches:

**RegEx [1]**

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?])[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d\-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]{8,}[a-zA-Z\d]$

^                               // Matches the start of the string
(?=.*[A-Z])                     // Positive lookahead to cheack for presence of a uppercase letter
(?=.*[a-z])                     // Positive lookahead to cheack for presence of an lowercase letter
(?=.*\d)                        // Positive lookahead to cheack for presence of a number
(?=.*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?])          // Positive lookahead to cheack for presence of a special character letter
[a-zA-Z\d]                      // Matches a "non-special" character at the start of the string
[a-zA-Z\d\-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]{7,}   // Matche any allowed character 7+ times
[a-zA-Z\d]                      // Makes sure the last (minimum 8th) character isn't special
$                               // Matches the end of the string
```

**RegEx [2]**

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=[a-zA-Z\d].*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?].*[a-zA-Z\d]$)[a-zA-Z\d\-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]{8,}$

^                                               // Matches the start of the string
(?=.*[A-Z])                                     // Positive lookahead to cheack for presence of a uppercase letter
(?=.*[a-z])                                     // Positive lookahead to cheack for presence of an lowercase letter
(?=.*\d)                                        // Positive lookahead to cheack for presence of a number
(?=[a-zA-Z\d].*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?].*[a-zA-Z\d]$)   // Positive lookahead to check that the string starts and ends with a letter or number but contains a special character
[a-zA-Z\d\-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]{8,}                   // Matches any allowed character 8+ times
$                                               // Matches the end of the string
```

**Output**

```
_Password               [1]         [2]
---------------------------------------
abcdef                   0   =>      0
abcDEF                   0   =>      0
abcDEF789_               0   =>      0
_123DEF789               0   =>      0
abc_DEF123               1   =>      1
abc_D1                   0   =>      0
abc%defghi               0   =>      0
some pass                0   =>      0
Some Other Pass_1234     0   =>      0
alpha_Numeric$12         1   =>      1
Random_1#@!S             1   =>      1
RRARaa???23              1   =>      1
```